# Wrapper needed? Looking for assistance

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am attempting to display a VF page listing contacts under a Tier Level.  Tier Level is a custom object that is a lookup field on the account record.  For example, a contact belongs to an account.  The account has an assigned Tier Level.  I have the below controller.  I am just putting the Contact, Account, and  Tier Level records in three different lists.  I then have a VF page that can print the lists individually.  I need to tie together the Contact List and the Tier Level list so that it displays...
Tier Level 1
    Contact 1
    Contact 2
Tier Level 2
     Contact 3
     Contact 4

I am not sure how to tie the lists together to accomplish this.  Below is my code:

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class TierList_CC {

    public List<Account> accountList{get;set;}
    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    public List<Fee_and_Discount__c> feeList{get;set;}

    public TierList_CC() {

        accountList = new List<Account>();
        contactList = new List<Contact>();
        feeList = new List<Fee_and_Discount__c>();

        feeList = [select id, Name  from Fee_and_Discount__c  ];
        contactList = [select id, LastName, FirstName, account.name, account.tier_level__r.name 
                       from Contact where GC_Rep__c=true 
                       order by account.name ];
    }    
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="FutureMeetings_CC" sidebar="false" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Organizations and GC Contacts">
        <apex:repeat value="{!feeList }" var="fee">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!fee.name}">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="con">
                    <apex:column value="{!con.account.name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!con.Firstname}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!con.Lastname}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Create wrapper  and pass the wrapper class to visualforce page

Comment: Why not just do a single query on Account (including the tier level) with a subquery to contacts. Then you can use a map to store the accounts by tier and display as needed on your VF page. You could also use a wrapper instead of the map but seems like you would only need a single query to get the data